# VS Code Java debugger freeezes at certain lines of code

Tags: java, debugging, visual-studio-code

I've been making a simple server that receives messages from multiple clients, then returns "hello" to the client. However, when I debug the program I run into issues, where some lines of code seem to freeze the debugger. This happens when I step through the program while debugging, and certain lines will cause me not to be able to continue stepping through the program. The "Continue", "Step Over", "Step Into", and "Step Out" can be clicked, but they don't advance the program.

Here is just one of the problem code blocks:

```
if(key.isReadable()){
    String message = readFromChannel(key);
    System.out.println(message); // Debugger always freezes here
    sendToChannel(key, "hello");
}
```

I have never seen `System.out.println()` block, and I am thoroughly confused as to why this line of code seems to freeze the program.

Any help appreciated, as this is incredibly annoying.

I am using VS Code on MacOS Catalina, v1.14.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be caused by the expressions in the Watch tab. It works fine after I removed all the expressions from under the tab.