# Java debugger stuck on line in vscode

Tags: java, debugging, visual-studio-code

first of all I want to point out that my exact same question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59864191/vs-code-java-debugger-freeezes-at-certain-lines-of-code), yet the solution there doesn't help here.

when I debug java in vscode, the current debugged line isn't moving to the next line, but stays on the same line.

it doesn't happen with simple lines like integer variable declaration, but it happens when I try to print using the `System.out.println`, and when I tried to create a `new` object.

------------ edit ------------

[an example gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTkcY.gif)

no extensions are install except for "Java Extension Pack".

---

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you install any other extensions like Live Share? Only keep Extension Pack for Java, can you share your code and record a gif when debugging?

Comment: @MollyWang-MSFT added to my question

Answer (score 0):

Add breakpoint at the `print` sentence, it will step into `.class` files and execute the code step by step. But in your cases, it indeed executed while didn't open new `.class`, which made you mistake your java debugger stuck on the line.

When encountered this kind of questions, step over it then step into, you can get the logo moved to next line:

[image]

The question that clicking step into won't open .class files, please file a bug report in [github/vscode-java-debug](https://github.com/microsoft/java-debug/issues).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I switched the java runtime to the one it recommeds downloading and it solved it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).